# SQL Server :: Replication Distribution Agent never ending

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, sql-server-2019, alwayson, availability-group

I'm running SQL Server 2019 Always ON Availability Group with an asynchronous replication.

I use a free tool called [IDERA SQL Check](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqlcheck) and I have spotted the `SPID 69` which program name is `Replication Distribution Agent`. It's always there, staring at me like a bored cat.

[image]

This `SPID 69` is pointing to a specific database which is **mirrored** I investigated it with this the query:

```
select 
s.session_id
,login_name
,login_time
,host_name
,program_name
,status
,cpu_time
,memory_usage
,total_scheduled_time
,total_elapsed_time
,last_request_start_time
,reads
,writes
,logical_reads
from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
inner join sys.dm_exec_connections c
on s.session_id = c.session_id
outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) st
where s.is_user_process = 1
and s.open_transaction_count > 0;
```

Which gave me this response:

- session_id = 69
- text = begin tran
- login_time = 2020-09-08 18:40:57.153
- program_name = Replication Distribution Agent
- status = sleeping
- cpu_time = 1362772
- memory_usage = 4
- total_scheduled_time = 1689634
- total_elapsed_time = 22354857
- last_request_start_time = 2020-09-28 16:28:39.433
- reads = 18607577
- writes = 5166597
- logical_reads = 112256365

Now, on internet I find that when you see `Replication Distribution Agent` is all good, that agent should be going and there should be no problem. But why:

1. The text says `begin tran` and nothing more?
2. IDERA SQL Check is labelling it as `connection idling transaction`?
3. The status is `sleeping`?
4. I'm concerned that `CPU time, reads and writes` are basically telling me that this process is frying the drive with never ending I/O, am I right?

Comment: you might get better help over at https://dba.stackexchange.com or [sf] but this place is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thank you @user3788685, they banned me from dba.stackexchange.com .
...And I'm a DBA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

The replication distribution agent is effectively running continuously to scan the transactions on your source to be able to send them to the replicas.   Because it needs to capture these and forward them, it has to run continuously.

It is not frying your drive - unless your transaction rate is so high that that is actually frying your drive.  It shows high reads in an incremental manner - this is cumulative values and not a snapshot of current. That suggests that it has read the equivalent of 141GB over 20 days - not particularly heavy use.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, also the 'begin tran' is normal?

Comment: Actually, check also whether you have enabled replication on this instance.  Do you have a distribution database?  There may be components of that which have been installed that are incorrectly configured which might be causing this actual process to show up since it normally doesn't show for an AG

Comment: Exactly @Martin. I have 4 databases on that machine but this process is running constantly just on 1 of them. And there is this `begin tran` and then nothing more, no code, like if someone forgot to paste the query after that `begin tran`. I will keep you updated. Many thanks

Comment: Can you run `select name, is_published, is_subscribed, is_merge_published, is_distributor
  from sys.databases
  where is_published = 1 or is_subscribed = 1 or
  is_merge_published = 1 or is_distributor = 1` and see what it has for the database where you see this issue

Comment: Your query returns nothing. And the `SPID 69` is still there going around like every day and night

Comment: What about `DBCC OPENTRAN(7)`